# cppwinrt doesn't generate Generated Files\Sources sometimes #include "BlankUserControl.g.h" not found

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml, c++-winrt

Even simple BlankPage or BlandUserControl created from the wizard fails - as the header #include "BlankUserControl.g.h" is not found

Comment: Could you please post some code?

Comment: Have you written the `.g.h` part yourself? It should be just `#include "BlankUserControl.h"`

Comment: //
// Declaration of the BlankPage class.
//

#pragma once

#include "BlankPage.g.h"

namespace winrt::VideoApp::implementation
{
    struct BlankPage : BlankPageT<BlankPage>
    {
        BlankPage();

        int32_t MyProperty();
        void MyProperty(int32_t value);

        void ClickHandler(Windows::Foundation::IInspectable const& sender, Windows::UI::Xaml::RoutedEventArgs const& args);
    };
}

Comment: It seems to have generated "Generated Files\BlankPage.xaml.g.h" but "BlankPage.h" is referencing "BlankPage.g.h"

Comment: No, i have not written .g.h part. Obvisiously, this works when you start a new and blank project. Under some conditions, adding to a new Page to existing project  this failure occurs. Might the Xaml compiler fails due to other issues. But no error message.

Comment: I tried make a blank cpp winrt project and include  #include "BlankUserControl.g.h". Unfortunately, I could not reproduce this issue.

Comment: Obviously, this doesn't happen when you start from scratch and simple project. This happens in a medium size project. Shall I send you the source code ? My sense is the xaml compiler craps silently and generates partial set of files.

Comment: Sure, you could share us with project and I will test.

Comment: where do I send it ? email ?

Comment: You could share the sample for us with github.

Answer (score 0):

Try placing the XAML files into project's top-level folder

Comment: Please avoid the impression of asking instead of answering. You can achieve that by phrasing more assertively, e.g. "If your problem is .... then the solution is to ....".